# Regexp_Extract nth position in delimited string

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I have a string in the format:

```
abc_fjs_dja_sja_dj_sadjasdksa_sdjakd_match_fsja_fsdk
```

I want to `REGEXP_EXTRACT` the string in the 8th delimited position (`_` as the delimiter).

How would I do this using the Regex syntax used in DataStudio?

I have tried this: `(?:[^_]*_){8}(.*?)`

But this matches anything up to and including the 8th delimited segment of the string, whaeras I want JUST the 8th segment.

Thanks

Comment: Try: `(?:[^_]+_){7}\K([^_]*)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may unwrap the pattern a bit and capture 0 or more chars other than `_` after the first seven `_` delimited parts with `([^_]*)`:

```
^(?:[^_]*_){7}([^_]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bgG0eu/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^_]*_){7}` - 7 repetitions of

  - `[^_]*` - 0 or more chars other than `_`
  - `_`  - an underscore
- `([^_]*)` - Capturing group 1: 0 or more chars other than `_`

`REGEXP_EXTRACT` returns the contents of the capturing group.